# Is my proof for $m|a\land m|b\Longrightarrow m|\alpha a+\beta b$ correct?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, divisibility

I just did a proof for $m\mid a\ \land m\mid b\Longrightarrow m\mid (\alpha a+\beta b)$ but it feels a bit weak. Can someone please check it and let me know if it is complete? Thank you in advance.

---

\begin{align*}
m\mid a\ \land m\mid b
&\Longrightarrow \exists k_1\in\mathbb Z:a=k_1m\ \land\ \exists k_2\in\mathbb Z:b=k_2m\\
&\Longrightarrow\alpha a+\beta b=\alpha k_1m+\beta k_2m=m(\alpha k_1+\beta k_2)\end{align*}

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I'm not clicking on a link from a new user nor do I recommend anyone else do so either. Please look over the MathJax tutorial again.

Comment: It is correct, and works in any ring - see the dupe. Please delete the dupe question.